# How to get the default duration of a GIF image

Tags: image, flutter, dart, gif

I'm forking [flutter_gifimage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gifimage) cause it's last update was in Nov 7, 2019, to migrate it to null safety.

I've used this package in an old project and it worked fine but one thing that stumbled me is it provides no way to get the default GIF duration, I needed to hard-code it.

What i want is to get the default duration of the GIF from the `ImageProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

hope u find the answer to your question.
but for anyone that has the same question, I tried to search about it but with no results!
so I came up with an idea.
we will track the frames till the end, so now we have the frames of our GIF.
Now all we need to do is get the frame rate to divide the frames by the frame rate to get the duration, it will look something like this `(totalFrame/frameRate).round()` if you would like to get it with milliseconds -to be specific- you can add `((totalFrame/frameRate)*pow(10, 3)).round()`.
Now u are wondering how to track the frames and get the frameRate, the answer is simple, all you have to do is add [GifView](https://pub.dev/packages/gif_view) package to your dependencies.
you can track the frames by using `onFrame:(){}` and the default frameRate is 15 FPS and here's a sample:

```
GifView.asset(
                'assets/onBoarding1-2.gif',
                onFrame: (value) =>  duration = ((value/15)*pow(10, 3)).round(),
                onFinish: () => defaultDuration = duration;
              ),
```